# qwt - a scroll bar appears without any reason

Tags: plot, scrollbar, qwt

I have a plotWidget class which is responsible for plotting data on a QwtPlot *plot (the  QwtPlot *plot is a member of my plotWidget class).

My problem is the following:

1. The user chooses how many different curves he wants to plot.
2. Then the program attaches to the plot as many QwtPlotCurves as the user chose (one after another, using the function attach( QwtPlot *plot ) ).
3. If the user chose more than 20 curves, a scroll bar appears on the plot (while adding the first point to the first curve using the function setRawSamples()).

The user can drag the scroll bar, but it has no effect - the plot fits to its container.

Why is it happening and how can I stop  it?

Answer (score 0):

The only element on a plot that has an optional scroll bar is the legend.